# Java threads and synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock, synchronized

Suppose I'm executing a `synchronized` block of code inside some thread and within the `synchronized` block I call a method that spawns another thread to process a synchronized block of code that requires the same lock as the first method. So in pseudo Java code:

```
public void someMethod() {
  synchronized(lock_obj) {
    // a whole bunch of stuff...

    // this is the last statement in the block
    (new Thread(someOtherMethod())).start();
  }
    // some more code that doesn't require a lock
}

public void someOtherMethod() {
  // some setup code that doesn't require a lock

  // return the stuff we want to run in another thread
  // that does require a lock
  return new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      synchronized(lock_obj) {
        // some more code
      }
    }
  };
}
```

I have no idea how to make sense of that code. Is what I have written even legal? Syntactically I don't see any issues but I'm not sure how to reason through code like that. So when I execute `someOtherMethod()` in order to create an instance of `Runnable` in what kind of scope does the code before the return statement run? Does it execute as part of the first synchronized block? Assume there are some other threads working as well that might require the lock on `lock_obj`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are still holding the lock during the creation of runnable and the thread, but after you call start and before the thread actually picks up you are relinquishing the lock. The new thread will have to compete for the lock with other threads.

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing wrong about this code. Before the return statement in `someOtherMethod()`, the code is running in the synchronized block of `someMethod()`. After the new thread starts, it will block on the `synchronized` statement inside the `run()` method until it obtains a lock on `lock_obj` (at the earliest, whenever `someMethod()` exits its synchronized block).

Comment: just adding something that might be missed - the synchronized block in someMethod() is exited as soon as start() is called, and the new thread is executing parallely. This seems to have been what caused the OP's confusion.

Comment: @AbrahamPhilip - I wouldn't put it that way. The synchronized block is _not_ exited when `start()` is called. (It does exit a very short time later, because the call to `start()` happens to be the last statement in the synchronized block.) Rather, calling `start()` initiates execution of another thread (which begins with no monitors held), running the code in the `Runnable` returned by `someOtherMethod()`. That other thread needs to wait for the block in `someMethod()` to exit before it can enter its own synchronized block.

Comment: sorry, you're absolutely right. Let me rephrase, "right after" start() is called. I just wanted to highlight that because the OP was wondering whether the second thread's runnable was executing within the first synchronized block (as an answer here erroneously claimed http://stackoverflow.com/a/5295252/3000919). I believe your comment explains that very well though, thankyou :)

Answer (score -2):

If someMethod() is invoked first, its the classical example of a deadlock.

**Is what I have written even legal?**
---- Yes it is perfectly legal syntactically.

**So when I execute someOtherMethod() in order to create an instance of Runnable in what kind of scope does the code before the return statement run?**
----If the someOtherMethod() is invoked from within someMethod() then its in scope of the synchronized block of the someMethod() method.

Comment: Why is it a deadlock? Thread.start returns immediately and at that point the lock on lock_obj is released at which point the Runnable that was returned either picks up the lock or waits on some other thread to release it.

Comment: Agree with @davidk01 that this is not a deadlock. And it certainly isn't 'the classical' example of one if it was. Just for further information, even without the thread start, calling a method in java that is synchronized on the same lock a thread already holds will not block, since the caller already owns the lock.