# Execution of new thread inside a synchronized block

Tags: java, synchronized

If i create a new thread inside a synchronized block, will the block remain locked till the thread execution is also complete? 
If not, then till when would it remain locked?

```
String sLine;
onClick(String line){
    synchronized (lock) {
        sLine = line;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 doProcessing(Sline);    
        }).start(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295065/java-threads-and-synchronized-blocks?rq=1

Comment: @rajesh no. The question you reference covers the scope of this question, but is a different question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would only remained locked if the code [`join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join())d with the newly created thread, thus waiting for it to finish. As there is no `join()` the lock will be released after the call to `start()` has completed.

Comment: so in the above case it block would be locked only till the new thread has been created? so it won't wait till run() is completed?

Answer (score 1):

no thread has a separate life. synchronized block will be blocked only till starting point of the thread in above case.